# Dynamic Background Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

Here's [a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120216205630/beckabney.com/test.html) to what I'll be referring to.

I'm having some trouble getting the background image to work the way I'd like it to.

I want the background to auto resize based on the width of the window, which it is already doing correctly. If you make your window smaller you'll see the background shrink with it.

Here's the issue. If you make your window wide (short) then the background will resize and go too high so you can't see the top of the background anymore (since the background is bottom positioned).
**I want the background to be top position when you are at the top of the page, and as you scroll down it will slowly move to be bottom positioned.** Sort of like the effect of an Android phone's background when you move left and right. Of course, keep in mind that I still want the background to auto-resize when you make the window smaller.

```css
html {
  background-color: #70d4e3;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  margin-top: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -9999;
}

.banner {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 991px;
  margin-bottom: -9px;
}

.content {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/daRJl.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
  height: 889px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 869px;
}

.innerContent {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/6d5Cm.jpg" alt="" class="background" />

<div class="banner">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JptsZ.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="innerContent">
    testing
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe some javascript or jquery would be needed to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this was fun, thanks!

I hope you don't mind me taking the liberty to use percentages to make my life a little bit easier and possibly the script slightly more robust since I can reliably use floats with percentages.

What I did is make the layout, html and css comply with the rules you need for the bg to be animated properly, they stayed largely the same from what you had.

Then it was just a question of figuring out the calculations needed with the right properties to figure out the percentage you were from the top, the `*20` is actually the amount of space 'left' to fill by the background image in percentages (as the background height is 80%).

They I moved the calculations to a function so I could call that on scroll and on window resize, making sure it's initiated on any event that modifies the window somehow...

Didn't do extensive testing but it worked in Chrome and I'm tired :p

I believe this is what you are looking for:

<s>http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/RSqrw/15/ See edit 2</s>

If you wanted this the other way arround just make the page background start at the top and modify that:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/RSqrw/14/ See edit 2

**Edit:**

As a bonus, and since I had never actually written jquery script as a 'plugin', I decided to convert this into one. What I came up with should be easy to implement and use!

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/RSqrw/52/  See Edit 3

<s>Functionality successfully tested in Chrome, Firefox 3.6, IE9 + compatibility mode</s>

**Edit 2:**

Reading the question again checking if I did it right I noticed I didn't quite do what you want, so I updated the link in the first edit which gives you a plugin in which you can have several options for the scrolling background. It retains my 'old' interpetation while also doing what you want... Read comments in code for some extra descriptions.

**Edit 3:**

As I went to work today I was bothered with the fact that my plugin 'try' was a little bloated. And as you mentioned in the comment it didn't quite fit the requirements.

So I rewrote it to only do what you want and not much more, tested in Chrome Firefox, IE9 +compat etc etc.. This script is a lot cleaner.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/vZxHW/

You can chose to make the background stick to the top or bottom if the height fits in the window. Nothing else, but that is already more than enough to do some pretty cool stuff :p

Comment: Awesome... I've got one suggestions (make you really earn that bounty haha) If you make the window really narrow width then there is a gap at the bottom because of the top align. Could you make a modification so that if the window height is larger than the current height of the image, automatically just align it to the bottom?

Comment: Could't you make it with just css like that: http://jsfiddle.net/vZxHW/34/ . What's the difference?

Comment: @NiematojakTomasz I don't want the image to get squished awkwardly when resized

Comment: @sg3s Perfect! I'll be rewarding you the bounty. Mostly because of the fact that I could easily use this for any background size, and because this is the solution I've chose to use. Thanks!

Comment: the page seems to be positioning to the bottom by default until you scroll... could it default that based on the jquery?

Answer (score 3):

#### An exact solution: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srGHE/2/show/

View **[source](http://fiddle.jshell.net/srGHE/2/)**

Thanks for the challenge. See below for the solution, which is complying with all requirements, including recommended yet optional (with steps on how to remove these) features. I only show the changed parts of your page, with an explanation after each section (CSS, HTML and JavaScript):

**CSS (changes)**:

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: #70d4e3;  
}
#background { /*Previously: .background*/
    /*Removed: margin-top: 45px;
      No other changes*/
}
#banner /*Previously: .banner; no other changes */
#content /*Previously: .content; no other changes */
#innerContent /*Previously: .innerContent; no other changes */
```

Explanation of CSS revisions:

1. `margin-top:45px` at the background is unnecessary, since you're absolutely positioning the element.
2. All of the elements which are unlikely to appear more than once should be selected via the id (`#`) selector. This selector is more specific than the class selector.

**HTML (changes)**:
All of the `class` attributes have been replaced by `id`. No other changes have been made. Don't forget to include the [JQuery framework](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js), because I've implemented your wishes using JQuery.

**JavaScript** (new):
Note: I have added a feature which you didn't request, but seems logical. The code will automatically reserve sufficient margin at the left side of the window in order to always display the background. Remove anything between the marked comments if you don't want this feature.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //"Static" variables
    var background = $("#background");
    var marginTop = parseFloat(background.css("margin-top")) || 0;
    var bannerWidth = $("#banner").width(); /*Part of auto left-margin */
    var extraContWidth = (bannerWidth - $("#content").width())/2; /*Same as above*/

    function fixBG(){
        var bodyWidth = $("body").width();
        var body_bg_width_ratio = bodyWidth/1920;
        var bgHeight = body_bg_width_ratio * 926; //Calcs the visible height of BG
        
        var height = $(document).height();
        var docHeight = $(window).height();
        var difHeight = bgHeight - docHeight;
        var scrollDif = $(document).scrollTop() / (height - docHeight) || 0;
        
        /*Start of automatic left-margin*/
        var arrowWidth = body_bg_width_ratio * 115; //Arrow width
        if(bodyWidth - bannerWidth > arrowWidth*2){
            $("body > div").css("margin-left", "auto");
        } else {
            $("body > #banner").css("margin-left", arrowWidth+"px");
            $("body > #content").css("margin-left", (arrowWidth+extraContWidth)+"px");
        }
        /*End of automatic left-margin*/
        
        if(difHeight > 0){
            background.css({top:(-scrollDif*difHeight-marginTop)+"px", bottom:""});
        } else {
            background.css({top:"", bottom:"0"});
        }
    }
    $(window).resize(fixBG);
    $(window).scroll(fixBG);
    fixBG();
});
```

***Explanation of the JavaScript code***
The size of the background is determined by calculating the ratio of the background and document **width**. The width property is used, because it's the most reliable method for the calculation.

Then, the height of the viewport, document body and background is calculated. If applicable, the scrolling offset is also calculated, to prepare the movement of the background, if necessary.

*Optionally*, the code determines whether it's necessary to adjust the left margin (to keep the background visible at a narrow window).

Finally, if the background arrow has a greater height than the document's body, the background is moved accordingly, taking the scrolling position into account. The arrow starts at the top of the document, and will move up as the user scrolls (so that the bottom side of the arrow will be the bottom of the page when the user has fully scrolled down). If it's unnecessary to move the background, because it already suits well, the background will be positioned at the bottom of the page.

When the page has finished loading, this functionality is added to the Resize and scroll events, so that the background is always at the right location.

If you've got any other questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: I would like to confirm that this solution does work for my questions. I appreciate the response!

Comment: It doesn't only work for your question, it also works with any background size. You can adjust the values, calculated at `body_bg_ratio`(width: 1920), `bgHeight`(height: 926), `arrowWidth`(absolute arrow width:115) to get it work with any background.

Answer (score 0):

well, I'm not sure if I understand you and why do you want to do that, but you can try adding 2 backgrounds (see http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ ), one with the top bg and another with the bottom bg but I think that if the page is not too long it will cause issues, so the other answer with pure CSS is as follows: first add 3 horizontal divs with 100% width. Top div will have your top bg and its height, middle div will be transparent and auto height and bottom div will have your bottom bg and its height. All divs will have a 0 z-index. Then create a higher z-index div to act as a container and you'll be set. If I understand your question right, that's the close I can think of to achieve that. This being said, I'm pretty sure you can do this with JQuery with way better results

Comment: 2 images won't really work for this situation because I'm wanting to show the full image... There probably is a javascript method of doing what I need, but I haven't figured it out yet

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery I was able to give you what I think you're asking for:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var h = Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height());
    var bottom = h - $(".background").height() - $(window).height();
    $(".background").css("top", (($(window).scrollTop() / h) * bottom) + "px");
});
```

EDIT: Forgot to account for the way scrollTop reports position.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe:

```
.background {
    margin-top: 45px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -9999;
    max-height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend using jQuery Background Parallax
http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Jquery-Background-Parallax/

The function is as simple as

```
$("body").backgroundparallax();
```

Ask if you don't get it to work.

Comment: Would take some slight modification for my situation, but still a handy solution. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

@abney; as i understand your question may that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/RSqrw/60/

you need only css for this:

```
#background {    
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0;
    left:0;   
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: That bit of code just shrinks/expands the background when the window resizes. Nothing happens when the user scrolls down. I believe that the OP wants a dynamic background, showing feedback when the user scrolls at a narrow window.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your issue is a nice little lightweight plugin by Scott Robin. You can get more info, download it, and make your life easier for all of your projects by visiting his project page [here](http://srobbin.com/blog/jquery-plugins/jquery-backstretch/).

Comment: Not a problem. I've incorporated this into my framework and love it to death - all you need to do is call it via `$.backstretch("path_to_image");`.