# Scroll background image untill the end not further

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site and I don't want to `repeat` the background in the y direction.

I know how to do that.

But after the image I don't want background to becomes white or any other color.

I would like it to fix when it reaches that place or to let the background scroll slower then the rest of the site so I wont get to a white part.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So, you don't want just a solid-color background _ever_, but you also don't want the background fixed and can't tile it vertically. Is that correct?

Comment: cdeszaq is kind a correct i want that user see the last part of the image that they won't see if i fix it.
Check also mij coment on quoo's answer

Comment: Are you looking for something like **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srGHE/2/show/)**? (explanation of logic at **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459553/dynamic-background-scrolling/7492610#7492610)**)

Comment: It may be beneficial to re-word your question into clear and concise sentences which lay out exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this thread while I was looking for a solution to just this problem. I managed to write a short jQuery script adapting the hints given by Alex Morales.

With the following code, the background-image of the body scrolles down with the rest of the site until its bottom is reached. You can take a look at my homepage (http://blog.neonfoto.de) to see what it does.

```
$( window ).scroll( function(){
  var ypos = $( window ).scrollTop(); //pixels the site is scrolled down
  var visible = $( window ).height(); //visible pixels
  const img_height = 1080; //replace with height of your image
  var max_scroll = img_height - visible; //number of pixels of the image not visible at bottom
//change position of background-image as long as there is something not visible at the bottom  
if ( max_scroll > ypos) {
     $('body').css('background-position', "center -" + ypos + "px");
  } else {
    $('body').css('background-position', "center -" + max_scroll + "px");
  }
});
```

This is actually the very first thing I did with JavaScript and JQuery, so any improvement would be great!

Answer (score 0):

It's css3 so it's not super well supported, but I would look at the [background-size](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) property.

Comment: That is not exactly what i mean. After a lot of searching i found that i need the parallax effect like in this example http://inner.geek.nz/javascript/parallax/
but a bit different. I have 2 options
1) the background image move at normal speed but stops moving when the end of the image is at the bottom of the page.
2) the background image moves at a speed so it the end reaches the bottom on the page at the moment u are scrolled till the end of the page.
I dont know how i have to change the example to reach one of the two options. Kan someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is just off the top of my head but I think you will probably have to create a separate div containing the background image. If you place it in your markup before the main content and position the main content absolutely, it will sit behind the main content and at the top of the page. So:

CSS:

```
 #background_div
{ 
  background: url(images/some_image.png); 
  height: 600px; 
  width: 900px; 
}

#main
{
  height: 1200px;
  width: 800px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="background_div"> &nbsp; </div>
```

Then what you do is you use javascript (I recommend jQuery) to detect the div's position on the screen.

jQuery:

This code grabbed from http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/

```
var $scrollingDiv = $("#background_div");

    $(window).scroll(function(){            
        $scrollingDiv
            .stop()
            .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px"}, "slow" );                    
    });
```